# store files in dynamoDB reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-dynamodb

how to store resume files in DynamoDB table, I already have a table which stores name and email, etc, I need to store files in it.
Using Reacts AWS, I already tried it using.

```
<input  name="my_file" onChange={e => updateFormState('resume', e.target.value)} type="file" className="form-control" required />
```

But it's not storing anything in DynamoDB.

how to store it in DynamoDB. I have got no answers searching this in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB has hard [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-data-types) on an item size of **400 KB**. This makes it not suitable for storing any files except the smallest ones.

Thus, instead of **string files in S3**, the files should be stored in S3, and the DyanmoDB would just store the metadata of these files (e.g. file name, creation timestamp, etc).

Comment: but how can we do that , is there any documentation.

Comment: @anonymousmkv You have to develop such a solution yourself as it is use-case specific. A good start would be understanding show DynamoDB and S3 work. Documentation for these services can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/index.html).